# Unable to submit form using jquery submit method

Tags: php, jquery

What i am trying to do is:

1. post a form when user is logged in.
2. but if he is not logged in then pop up login is shown to user.
3. and in that popup redirection URL is added to hidden field.
4. when popup opens and i login it redirect me to that form.
5. But when i try to submit form it not being submitted.

   ```
   //  submit button in form
   $('#submitcompanyEnquiry').on('click',function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       //get data attr to check if user is login
       if($('#companyEnquiry').data('login')){
           //companyEnquiry =>form id 
           //here i try to submit form  
            console.log('testing');    --->it is working
           jQuery('#companyEnquiry').submit();   ---> //the problem is here this piece of code is executing
       }else{
           if($('#companyEnquiry').attr('action')!=''){
               //here i added the current url to hidden field latter to used for redirection
               $('#loginForm #redirectUrl').val($('#companyEnquiry').data('seotitle'));
           }
           //here the login popup is trigger.
           jQuery("#login").trigger('click');
       }
   });
   ```

Things that I confirmed:

1. ensure that there is unique id with the
   name provided.
2. console some value in the if block which was
   running but the line of code i have mention.

**PHP part is working fine i have removed the `e.preventDefault();`
it is works fine but doesn't achieve the require functionality.**

**HTML Code**

```
                <form action="<?=Route::url('default',array('controller'=>'contact','action'=>'user_contact'))?>" data-login="<?php echo $data; ?>" data-seotitle="<?=Route::url('company', array('controller'=>'listing','seotitle'=>$company_seotitle))?>" id="companyEnquiry" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="company_to" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                     <?php if (!$auth->logged_in()) { ?>
                        <div class="input-group searchbox">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Name" name="name" required aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    <?php  }else { ?>
                        <div class="input-group searchbox">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Name" required value="<?php echo $auth->get_user()->company_name; ?>" name="name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if (!$auth->logged_in()) { ?>
                        <div class="input-group searchbox">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control search" placeholder="email" required name="company_from" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    <?php  }else { ?>
                       <div class="input-group searchbox">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control search" placeholder="email" required value="<?php echo $auth->get_user()->companyemail; ?>"  name="company_from" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if ($auth->logged_in()) { ?>
                    <div class="input-group searchbox">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="phone number" required name="phone" value="<?php echo $auth->get_user()->company_phone_1; ?>" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <div class="input-group searchbox">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="phone number" required name="phone" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <div class="input-group searchbox">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="subject" required name="subject" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group searchbox">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="message" required name="message" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                    </div>
                    <input data-login="<?php echo $data; ?>" id="submitcompanyEnquiry"  type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" class="form-control blue-btn send-btn">
                </form>
```

Comment: why do you use `jQuery` inside `if condition` instead of `$` ? Is there any reason ?

Comment: Hi,nope these is no reason but it still doesn't work when i use $.

Comment: does the $('#companyEnquiry').data('login') function returns you desired login value ? maybe its not exisiting ?

Comment: yes it does works.

Comment: i updated the question please look in to `if` block region

Comment: can you confirm that `$('#companyEnquiry')` is a `form` element?

Comment: pleas append your html code

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0):

The problem can only exist in the way you are adding the login variable to the form with the id : companyEnquiry

Check if you have add it as correct parameter because jquerys data function will only read values which have a "data-" tag infront of it.

So your php code should look like this :

```
echo '<form id="companyEnquiry" ' . ($login ? 'data-login="1"' : '' . '>
```

Comment: but that appears to be working, as the `console.log("testing")` is being reached.

Comment: Then the only possible failure could be that the object with the id companyEnquiry is not a form element ...

Comment: i think the problem exist in the way you are adding the data-login. it has always an value so it will always enter the if. you should insert it like i did or you check the value in your js code

Comment: console.log("testing") is  being reached. 
the problem is the line below that is not working it has nothing to do with `data-login`.
because it is already in that block.

Comment: nope when the user is not login that block is not executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179915/discussion-between-nauman-ahmad-and-blacknetworkbit).